# For a random variable $X$ and any $\epsilon>0$, how to show that $X^2 \leq \epsilon^2 + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read in a proof of Lindeberg's condition on the central limit theorem that for a random variable $X$, and for any $\epsilon>0$, we have the statement:

$$
X^2 \leq \epsilon^2 + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}}
$$

My question is, is there a way to formally prove this result? I have that:

$$
X^2 \leq X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq\epsilon\}} + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}}
$$

and so it **seems** we can bound the above by $\epsilon$ but am not sure how to get this result either in a **rigorous** manner.

Thanks!

Comment: $X^{2}=X^{2}\chi_{\left\{\left\lvert X\right\rvert\le\epsilon\right\}}+X^{2}\chi_{\left\{\left\lvert X\right\rvert >\epsilon\right\}}$

Comment: Thanks, I can intuitively get why this is true, but is there a more formal way to derive this? Like by conditioning or something?

Comment: It has nothing to do with random variable. This simply follows from the inequality $$ x^2 \leq \epsilon^2 + x^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{|x| > \epsilon \}} = \begin{cases} \epsilon^2, & |x| \leq \epsilon \\ \epsilon^2 + x^2, & |x| > \epsilon \end{cases} $$ which is true for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: This decomposition is formal. You might want to see what a simple function is.

Comment: Can it be also be proven as: $X^2 = X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq\epsilon\}} + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}} = X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{X^2\leq\epsilon^2\}} + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}} \leq \epsilon^2 + X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>\epsilon\}}$?

Comment: Of course. That is a totally valid (and probably more illuminating) proof.

Comment: @SangchulLee I just saw what you wrote, your's is a much simpler way of looking at it thanks